# How to use remained bits of a byte to store value in it?

Tags: java, memory, char, integer

All of us know that Integer datatype can store values till 4 bytes, means 32 bits

so for example if we have

`int a = 2;`

it means `a = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010`

Is there any way to use the remained bits and store value in them and take them out when needed?

Let me take another example:

We have a computer system that only uses English alphabets and numbers (26 + 10), so the sum of them is `36`.

Like when when we have 256 characters in computer and `log_2(256) = 8 bits` and we use 8 bits to store values

`log_2(36)`= 6 bits
it means that 6 bit is enough for the values.

Here is the question:

how I can use only three bytes to store 4 characters in it?

base on `log2(36) = 6`

this [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzl5R.jpg) can show the idea better

Comment: I am not aware of a way to store `4` characters in `3` bytes but you can look at `byte` in java if you want a smaller datatype. As the name suggests the size of `byte` is `1` byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Base64

The [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding is exactly what you want, and it has Java implementations. From the Wiki

> Each Base64 digit represents exactly 6 bits of data. Three 8-bit bytes (i.e., a total of 24 bits) can therefore be represented by four 6-bit Base64 digits.

Java8's docs include Base64 [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html).

### Old, Unnecessarily Complicated Answer

To answer your question in particular, you can cram four characters into three bytes using [bit shifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts) and a custom binary encoding.

For example, if you were to encode the lowercase letters of the alphabet and digits as six-bit codes

```
Symbol  | Decimal | Binary
0       | 0       | 000000
1       | 1       | 000001
...
f       | 16      | 010000
...
o       | 25      | 011001
...
z       | 35      | 100011
...
EOF     | 63      | 111111
```

Then the string `foof` could be written as `010000 011001 011001 010000`. Most languages would prefer to represent this as three bytes, or `01000001 10010110 01010000`. This is `A搀` using the utf-8 binary encoding or `-63 22 -48` if you represent them as the `byte` type in Java.

I'm not terribly familiar with Java, but I know there are [several](https://c-for-dummies.com/blog/?p=1848) resources for C and other languages to read off the exact bit-values for some bytestream.